# how to make central admin config for a feature

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration

I am trying to deploy a feature to a farm environment (server 2016), say a custom list or library, but there is needed configuration I want at the top farm level that all the features can use (I only want it done once or handled by an admin and not at all the site levels). how do I do the admin portion? I am very new to SharePoint so please forgive all my ignorance.